# Is there a technical difference between invoking `wp-cron.php` and using `wp cron event run`?

Tags: wp-cron, wp-cli

For years I've been running cron by setting `DISABLE_WP_CRON` to true in `wp-config.php` and then setting up a cron on my server that runs like this:

```
* * * * * cd /path/to/site/public_html && /usr/local/bin/wp cron event run --due-now
```

But I am moving webhosting (same company, different offering) and the new setup doesn't allow me to setup cronjobs in this way, so they recommend setting up an external cronjob on a different system that calls `https://example.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron` via curl/wget. It boggles my mind, but okay, whatevs.

So my question is whether the `wp cron event run --due-now` command and invoking the `/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron` are EXACTLY the same or not? I think they might be very similar, but unsure if they are exactly the same or if, perhaps, there is some nuanced difference.

Comment: Not an answer however, I recently stumbled across an issue that is known to the WP development team where some WP Crons get deleted.  The reason has not yet been zeroed in on and a solution has not yet been presented.  So I've moved all of my 'mission critical' crons to third-party services because, like in your scenario, my most frequently used host, doesn't allow server CRONs.